# Microsoft Edge missing in Start menu and pins

Tags: browser, icons, windows-10, microsoft-edge

**Note: People have seem to have had issues doing this in Windows 10 pro, this could be because of Windows Updates. If the solution does not work, please use "Refresh your PC"**

I have just upgraded to Windows 10 and had to switch to a Microsoft account while setting up Cortana.

Along the process, it asks me to sign out and sign back in, which I do. Then after signing back in, Microsoft Edge is missing. From the taskbar, and the "All Apps" section of the start menu.

This only occurs **AFTER** I have added my Microsoft account. And the only way is to open a .HTML file like this one:

[image: The file I use to open Edge]

(The name was from my Windows 7 Dualboot Install)

and please **don't** say *"Just open the HTML file!"* I need a proper solution to this.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but you could create a desktop shortcut. Simply navigate to `C:\Windows\SystemApps` and open the folder starting with `MicrosoftEdge`. Inside that folder search for `MicrosoftEdge` or `MicrosoftEdge.exe` and right click it to create a shortcut.

Comment: I did that, but it won't open.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Although this isn't a solution, it might lead to an answer. I had to take my PC off our domain so I could do the Win10 upgrade process. I tested the OS including Edge and it worked great. I then put my PC back on the domain with a new profile (not the original domain profile). I now can't search for or launch Microsoft Edge. The app does appear in C:\Windows\SystemApps. If I find a solution i'll be sure to post it for you.

Comment: Don't post the answer in your question.  You're allowed and encouraged to answer your own questions.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Search for PowerShell in your start menu. Right-click it and choose "Run as Administrator".

At the PowerShell command prompt, enter: 
`Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppxManifest.xml"}`

Comment: With this command, MS Edge re-appears but all uninstalled apps also re-appears. However when I try to find for "edge" from start menu it is still not found but I can run from start > M > Microsoft Edge and pinned it.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the command to reinstall ONLY the EDGE browser. It will leave any other uninstalled apps alone.

Open PowerShell and run:

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers -Name Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml” -verbose}
```