# Microsoft Edge Not in Start Menu

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

Microsoft Edge Launches but does not appear in start menu. I type in Microsoft Edge in Cortana, but it does not show in list. I click on search in web and it launches a search using Edge - so I know it is on my computer. Once launched, how do I pin to start menu or taskbar?

Comment: This question has been asked for Windows 7, but the answer should be the same. Essentially, you can reinstall Edge using a powershell command: http://superuser.com/questions/948441/microsoft-edge-missing-in-start-menu-and-pins

Answer (score 0):

After you open Edge "right click" pin to start.
If you couldn't find it go to:
This PC > type "edge" up there in the long white box.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't find Edge, that just opens whichever browser you've already got set as default, which OP already knows how to do. When a program is running and in the task bar, the only options by right-clicking on the taskbar icon is to pin/unpin to the taskbar. You cannot pin to the Start menu from there.

Comment: Firefox is my default browser! and works for me, I mean pin it after your open edge!!!

Comment: Firefox is also my default, and on my computer this opens Firefox and runs a web search for the word "edge", which has been the default behavior of Explorer since at least Windows XP.

Comment: If I type Firefox it will open directly Firefox! If I type edge it will open edge! the same with chrome! only if you type "google or any other word" an option will appear to ask you what browser do you want to use, I use the white box as "a run" box. it's works!

Comment: I'm not saying yours doesn't behave this way. I AM saying that it is apparent that not EVERY computer behaves this way and so your answer MAY not work for everyone. I believe I know the cause too: When I type the name of a program that is in the path statement into the Explorer address field that program loads, and if it isn't a valid command, then it loads the default web browser and searches. So, to test, open your Run dialog and type "edge" and tell me what happens.